# PHP Word Count Function

Tags: php, arrays, string, word-count

I am attempting to write my first custom function. I understand that there are other functions out there that do the same thing that this does, but this one is mine. I have the function wrote, but I do not understand char_list as it pertains to functions and cannot figure out the third parameter of the [str_word_count function](http://php.net/str_word_count) in php. I think I need to this in a certain format to maintain periods, comma, semi-colons, colons, etc. Please note that double and single quotes are maintained throughout the function. It is bottom symbols that are strip from the string.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum' dolor sit amet, consectetur; adipiscing elit. Mauris in diam vitae ex imperdiet fermentum vitae ac orci. In malesuada."

function textTrim($text, $count){ 
  $originalTxtArry = str_word_count($text, 1);

  $shortenTxtArray = str_word_count(substr(text, 0,$count), 1);
  foreach ($shortenTxtArray as $i=>$val) {
    if ($originalTxtArry[$i] != $val) {
      unset($shortenTxtArray[$i]);
    }
  }
  $shortenTxt = implode(" ", $shortenTxtArray)."...";
  return $shortenTxt;
}
```

*Output*
Lorem ipsum' dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Mauris in diam...

*Notice the "," after amet is missing.*

Ignore the string of periods at the end, I concatenate those on to the end before the return

Thank You for all assistance.

Dave

Comment: Sorry, but what is your function supposed to do? What input do you send to it, what's the expected output, and what do you actually get?

Comment: What's your question @Dave?

Comment: The third argument is any other valid characters that can be in a word.  Look at the examples they provide, it seems pretty straight forward.  They have a '3' in the word fri3nd, without '3' in the third argument, the word is considered 'fri'.

Comment: @sjagr I modified my original post to answer your comment.

Comment: What is the purpose of this function, are you trying to limit the number of words?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Why when text that contains commas or periods for example goes into the function they do not come out the same way.

Comment: @Augwa Yes that is exactly what i am trying to do but also keep the whole word intact when it is outputted rather than chopped off

Comment: If you don't want to worry about losing punctuation, then you could just simply explode on a space then join.

Comment: So as it appears the third argument should be ',;' if you want the comma and semi-colon included.  Otherwise Augwa makes a good point about using explode.

Comment: @Augwa, please post that as an answer and I will mark it. I feel so stupid now. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated function to explode based on a space

```
function textTrim($str, $limit){ 
    /** remove consecutive spaces and replace with one **/
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);

    /** explode on a space **/
    $words = explode(' ', $str);

    /** check to see if there are more words than the limit **/
    if (sizeOf($words) > $limit) {
        /** more words, then only return on the limit and add 3 dots **/
        $shortenTxt = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $limit)) . '...';
    } else {
        /** less than the limit, just return the whole thing back **/
        $shortenTxt = implode(' ', $words);
    }
    return $shortenTxt;
}
```

Comment: Hey Man, that are errors all through that. But it gave me the right idea. I fixed everything. Will post answer in a minute

Comment: sorry about that, I didn't even test it. Updated function to resolve the syntax error.

Comment: I exclude the else state and just returned the implode function but they both have the right idea. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual about the third parameter, charlist:

> A list of additional characters which will be considered as 'word'

These are any characters outside the usual a-z which should be included as part of a word, and not causing a word to break.

If you look at example 1 on the PHP manual you linked to, it will show an example where the word 'fri3nd' is only classed as 1 word when 3 is included in the charlist parameter.

Comment: Put how do I make it so that commas and periods are preserved throughout function

Comment: based on the function definition and documentation, you would set your third parameter to be ",." (quote-comma-period-quote)

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php
function trimTxt($str, $limit){ 
    /** remove consecutive spaces and replace with one **/
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);

    /** explode on a space **/
    $words = explode(' ', $str);

    /** check to see if there are more words than the limit **/
    if (sizeOf($words) > $limit) {
       /** more words, then only return on the limit and add 3 dots **/
       $shortTxt = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $limit)) . 'content here';
    } else {
       /** less than the limit, just return the whole thing back **/
       $shortTxt = implode(' ', $words);
    }
    return $shortTxt;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't just write the code, explain it to the OP.